# Processing Array[Byte] in spark dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I have a dataframe df1 as below with schema:

```
scala> df1.printSchema
root
 |-- filecontent: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- filename: string (nullable = true)
```

The DF has filename and its content. The content is GZIPped. I could use something like the below to unzip the data in filecontent and save it to HDFS.

```
def decompressor(origRow: Row) = {
    val filename = origRow.getString(1)
    val filecontent = serialise(origRow.getString(0))

    val unzippedData = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(filecontent))

    val hadoop_fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
    val filenamePath = new Path(filename)

    val fos = hadoop_fs.create(filenamePath)

    org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(unzippedData, fos, sc.hadoopConfiguration)
    fos.close()
  }
```

**My objective:**

Since the filecontent column data in the df1 is a binary i.e Array[byte] i shouldnt distribute the data and have it together and pass it to the function so that it could decompress and save it to a file.

**My Question:**

1. How do I not distribute the data (column data)?
2. How do I make sure the processing happens for 1 row at a time?

Comment: If you don't want to distribute or parallelize don't use Spark? The only thing you can really do is collect or convert `toLocalIterator`.

Comment: distribution of data and parallel processing is the main theme of spark and hadoop. You can still process row by row in distributed manner.

Comment: df1 is a resultant of a very long MPP spark code and doing this row wise operation is one among the many steps.I need to restrict this to row wise operation for this scenario alone.